# Django and React

Tags: python, django

I haven't been able to locate anything saying one way or the other, but does anyone know if you can have function based views in django and have react as your frontend? No use of templates.

If so, would it look like this?

```
# fad index route

def fad_index(request):
    context = {'fads': Fad.objects.all()}
    return render(request, 'fad/fad_index.html', context)
```

But instead of fad_index.html, would it just be the route that you want it to take in react?

Answer (score 1):

When you use **Django** views, whether class or function based, you are required to render html responses, so there is no point on using **React** this way since the front-end functionality is already embedded in the html you are rendering.

**React** is thought for creating front-end applications that run independently from the back-end application. For that, the back-end application must provide specific url points for fetching or posting data from and to the front-end. These url points are known as end-points, and this back-end architecture is known as API, and come in two main flavors, SOAP and REST, and differ, basically, in the format of the data that comes from and goes to the front-end. SOAP APIs use xml, and REST APIs use json.

If you have a REST API back-end, you can use ajax in a **React** front-end to fetch and post data from and to the back-end's end-points.

For making a REST API back-end using **Django**, you need to complement it with another library called **Django Rest Framework**, that allows **Django** views to render json packages instead of html, so your **React** front-end  can use these end-points.

Answer (score 0):

React is simply a component composition library. You can use it to render single components on a web page or as the rendering layer of a more complex Single Page Application (SPA)

The general best practice when creating single page applications is to send the data over in a JSON format using a REST API. JSON because it can be parsed in almost any language and REST because the server should not care what the client is specifically doing.

There is a module called [django rest framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) that allows you to return raw data from REST style endpoints in a JSON format.